# sum field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, field, formula

I have two text fields in crystal report, `textA` and `textB`.
What if I wanted through the formula editor (not via c# code) set a third field called `textTot = textA + textB`.

What is the correct crystal report syntax?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplist formula is: `ToNumber({TableName.TextA}) + ToNumber({TableName.TextB})`.

However, it would be a good idea to first test whether the data is numeric (to avoid a runtime error):

```
Local NumberVar numericA;
Local NumberVar numericB;

If IsNumeric(Trim({textA})) 
    Then numericA = ToNumber(Trim({textA}))
    Else numericA = 0;

If IsNumeric(Trim({textB})) 
    Then numericB = ToNumber(Trim({textB}))
    Else numericB = 0;

numericA + numericB;
```